# AES encryption of directory in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I can encrypt and decrypt files in Cocoa in AES standard thanks to the NSData category [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html). However, I do not know how I can do the same thing with directories and folders. Is it possible to encrypt a folder, because I have seen that other security software can do it. Is there another class I can use?? 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First archive the directory, turning it into a file. There exist various Cocoa frameworks for this - many are listed here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ZipArchiveLibraryForCocoa

And then encrypt the archive file.